# Does Cucumber generates HTML build report for failed build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bamboo, parallel-testing

I have cucumber application. On Bamboo CI i trigger the build. For pass build cucumber generates HTML reports but for failed build it doesn't generates HTML report.

Please verify it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about cucumber but in Bamboo you can move Tasks to below that line whatever it is called, for the task to be executed disregard the exit codes of the previous tasks. This allows you to e.g. execute a task that generates documentation even in case that compilation fails.